# Append last and first element pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some menu that will be like this in HTML

```
    <ul class="main-menu menu-bees" id="menu-main-menu" data-menu-width="1112">
        <!-- rowTpl -->
        <li class="menu-item bees-start active" id="menu-item-0">
            <a href="#">
                MENU 1
                <div class="canvas_wrapper">
                    <canvas class="menu_dashed" height="64" width="501"></canvas>
                </div>
            </a>
            <span class="button_open"></span>

        </li>
        <!-- rowTpl -->
        <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-1">
            <a href="#">
                MENU 2
                <div class="canvas_wrapper">
                    <canvas class="menu_dashed" height="64" width="501"></canvas>
                </div>
            </a>
            <span class="button_open"></span>

        </li>
        <!-- rowTpl -->
        <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-2">
            <a href="#">
                MENU 3
                <div class="canvas_wrapper">
                    <canvas class="menu_dashed" height="64" width="501"></canvas>
                </div>
            </a>
            <span class="button_open"></span>
        </li>   
    </ul>
```

What i need is to append some html, ID#  **menu-item-xxx** will always counts and add number of elements in array starting from 0. 
I can not use Jquery i need pure JS for doing this, and that is that i need some extra HTML in first **`LI > A`** and in last, i dont know how many it will be but always has to append the last.
When i append html it has to look like this

```
    <ul class="main-menu menu-bees" id="menu-main-menu" data-menu-width="1112">
        <!-- rowTpl -->
        <li class="menu-item bees-start active" id="menu-item-0">
            <a href="#">
              **<p>FIRST</p>**
                MENU 1
                <div class="canvas_wrapper">
                    <canvas class="menu_dashed" height="64" width="501"></canvas>
                </div>
            </a>
            <span class="button_open"></span>

        </li>
        <!-- rowTpl -->
        <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-1">
            <a href="#">
                MENU 2
                <div class="canvas_wrapper">
                    <canvas class="menu_dashed" height="64" width="501"></canvas>
                </div>
            </a>
            <span class="button_open"></span>

        </li>
        <!-- rowTpl -->
        <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-2">
            <a href="#">
              **<p>LAST</p>**
                MENU 3
                <div class="canvas_wrapper">
                    <canvas class="menu_dashed" height="64" width="501"></canvas>
                </div>
            </a>
            <span class="button_open"></span>
        </li>   
    </ul>
```

It means I need to add :


First

 to first LI > a
and 


LAST

 to last LI > a

And all that by pure JS, any idea, count again that i dont know how many LI it will be :(

If i know how to write JS i would make a code, but i dont know where to start :(

Comment: Missing your JS code

Comment: If i know how to write JS i would make a code, but i dont know where to start :(

Comment: I know how to do that in Jquery, but on this project there is no Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` to select all `li` elements and then use `for` loop to check if its last or first `li` element and add HTML with `insertAdjacentHTML`.

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll('#menu-main-menu li');
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  if (i == 0) {
    li[i].querySelector('a').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<p>FIRST</p>');
  }

  if (i == (li.length - 1)) {
    li[i].querySelector('a').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<p>LAST</p>');
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu menu-bees" id="menu-main-menu" data-menu-width="1112">
  <!-- rowTpl -->
  <li class="menu-item bees-start active" id="menu-item-0">
    <a href="#">
                MENU 1
                <div class="canvas_wrapper">
                    <canvas class="menu_dashed" height="64" width="501"></canvas>
                </div>
            </a>
    <span class="button_open"></span>

  </li>
  <!-- rowTpl -->
  <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-1">
    <a href="#">
                MENU 2
                <div class="canvas_wrapper">
                    <canvas class="menu_dashed" height="64" width="501"></canvas>
                </div>
            </a>
    <span class="button_open"></span>

  </li>
  <!-- rowTpl -->
  <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-2">
    <a href="#">
                MENU 3
                <div class="canvas_wrapper">
                    <canvas class="menu_dashed" height="64" width="501"></canvas>
                </div>
            </a>
    <span class="button_open"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: TypeError: li[i].querySelector(...) is null

Comment: I will home more UL on the page, that can be problem

Comment: Try with id instead of `ul` also can you create fiddle with your actual html code.

Comment: Great now it works

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
<script>
        var menu = document.getElementById('menu-main-menu');
        var items = menu.getElementsByTagName('li');
        var len = items.length;

        for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            var li = items[i];
            li.setAttribute('id', 'menu-item-' + i);

            if (i === 0) {
                console.log('innerHTML: ' + li.innerHTML)
                li.innerHTML = '**<p>FIRST</p>**' + li.innerHTML;
            } else if (i === (len - 1)) {
                li.innerHTML = '**<p>LAST</p>**' + li.innerHTML;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Just realized you don't need to set the id on the li tags, it's already there. You can remove that code.